# How can they port the old console game to iPhone or Android?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, port

I've found the old console game like "Final Fantasy Tactics: The War of The Lions" on iPhone and Android and it's the same thing as I played in the console.

I want to know that how can they port the old console game like this to iPhone or Android?

After considering many mobile game engines, I've found that most of them based on C or C++ and I though that most console game are written by C or C++ as well so what's in my mind is that it's easy to port these games to iPhone or Android.

Anyone please confirm my idea if it's correct or suggest me the possible ways to port the console games to iPhone or Android.

Thank you very much.

Comment: No, it's not easy, but at least having sourcecode does make it easier. Given the mobile platform is UTTERLY different than a console environment (different CPU, different graphics, different audio, different operating system, blah blah blah), porting games is non-trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is almost never easy to port an old title to a different platform, although there are exceptions to this. ([Another World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Another_World_%28video_game%29) was written in an assembly-like language making it easier to port to other platforms).

Even if the game is in the same programming language, there are often API differences between platforms, and how hardware-related events are sent from the device to the game.

One common options is thus to write a simulator/emulator for the old hardware. If the new hardware is fast enough this will give you the exact experience of the old game without actually having to port the game itself. (The emulator could be then used to port multiple titles.)

If you find a game on a new device which has the same quirks as the old device, then it was most likely ported in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

The source code to those old console games is copyrighted. Otherwise, the source is not freely available - closed source.

You can probably find source code via ROMs, but if you ever tried to release a successful port of this code on a public market (android, ios etc) you would probably be slammed with a copyright notice if it even was approved.

In other words, this isn't really possible for a simple developer not affiliated with the company that owns the games' source code.